# Use hybrid elements inside Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, native

I had a cordova-based e-commerce app that I want to convert to flutter.

In that app, for any page I used to send an ajax request to a corresponding PHP page and fetch all the HTML, CSS and Javascript for that page and insert it into the document body. This enabled me to apply any UI or functionality change immediately without rolling out an app update, just by changing the PHP page.

I found out that there is no way to do the same thing natively in flutter. So I was wondering if I could just render hybrid HTML elements in flutter that can interact with the native components (without using a webview). In that way I would be able to create an app with non-changing parts like the top and bottom navigation, search, sidebar, etc. in native Flutter and the main body content in hybrid HTML that can be recieved via and http request. I found out that amazon does the same thing for there app, which can be verified by turning on "Show Layout Bounds" in developer options.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Check this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html